# Posicion de un item de un listview en Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Al seleccionar un item de un listview, quiero saber la posicion en la que se encuentra por ejemplo si se selecciona el primer elemento (Con un evento onTapped), que retorne si esta en la posicion 0 de la listview o que es el primer elemento de la lista.

XAML

```
<ListView
     ItemSource="{Binding Lista}"
     ItemTapped="Metodo_Tapped">
  <ListView.ItemLayout>
   <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Frame>
          <stacklayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Texto}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}"/>
          </stacklayout>
        </Frame>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemLayout>

</ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
async void Metodo_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as Frame;
    var x = item.X;
    var y = item.Y;
    await item.TranlateTo(x + 15, y +15);

}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Te invito a que leas la [bien venida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) en este sitio para que veas como preguntar y tu pregunta pueda ser solucionada lo mas pronto posible

Comment: Ok. Gracias por la sugerencia, aunque quizas de forma mas comprensible sería: Como saber en que posicion de la lista esta el elemento, al seleccionarlo,  si es el primer elemento de la lista, el segundo, el ultimo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

El ListView no tiene SelectedIndex como el Picker, pero podes capturar el item seleccionado.
Primero agregale un nombre a tu ListView

```
<ListView
     ItemSource="{Binding Lista}"
     ItemTapped="Metodo_Tapped" 
     x:Name=lstview>
  <ListView.ItemLayout>
   <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Frame>
          <stacklayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Texto}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}"/>
          </stacklayout>
        </Frame>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemLayout>

</ListView>
```

Segundo:

```
async void Metodo_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // en este metodo hago un cast sobre el elemento seleccionado. tenes que cambiar el (tuClase) ya que no pusiste con que clase rellenar el ListView
    var selecccion = (TuClase)lstview.SelectedItem;
    int i=0;
    foreach(var s in MiLista)
    {
       if(seleccion.equals(s)
          return;
       i++;
    }
    //En i tendrias el numero de index.

    var item = sender as Frame;
    var x = item.X;
    var y = item.Y;
    await item.TranlateTo(x + 15, y +15);

}
```